# Problemas com Group By no PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, heroku, group-by

Estou tentando fazer uma view em um banco de dados Postgre:

```
CREATE VIEW anuncio_points
AS
    SELECT
    a.*,
    (CASE WHEN p.points is null THEN 0 ELSE sum(p.points) END) + u.points as points
    FROM anuncios as a
    LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.user_id
    LEFT JOIN points as p ON p.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY a.id;
```

Porém esta retornando o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR:  column "p.points" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 5:     (CASE WHEN p.points is null THEN 0 ELSE sum(p.points) EN...
```

Já pesquisei em centenas de site porém eu só encontro o comando para MySQL eu habilita/desabilita essa função:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Se for possível de resolver o erro com um comando como este ultimo qual seria o seu equivalente em PostgreSQL?

Se for algum outro tipo de erro, alguém tem alguma solução? Já perdi algumas horas nisso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você utilizar o `sum` no `p.points` e no `u.points` soluciona seu problema, uma vez que eles não estão no group by.

```
CREATE VIEW anuncio_points AS SELECT
    a.*,
    ( SUM(p.points)  + SUM(u.points)) AS points
FROM
    anuncios AS a
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON
    u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN points AS p ON
    p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
    a.id;
```